# How to manage state of some property of JSON object in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and have some problems with managing state of my object. I described below what I want to do and the approach I take.

General idea is, I receive complex JSON object from REST service. One of the property of this larger JSON object is "reservation" it represents reservation for some project for some day. Reservation object has property "project", "hours" (they will be modified) and list of "availableProjects". Available projects will by display in drop down , an user can select it to update property "reservation.project". After filling all reservations, hours and some other properties I want to send this modified object back to the server.

Here is code:

```
var ReservationBox = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        reservation: this.props.reservation //IS THIS ANTI-PATTERN ?
    }
},
onSelectProject: function (selectedProject) {
    this.setState({reservation: {project: selectedProject}}); // IT WORKS but I don't know I did it correctly according to best practices :-)
},
handleHoursChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({reservation: {hours: e.target.value}}) // THIS DOES NOT WORK
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.name}
            <div className="btn-group timesheet-project-column">
                <button type="button"
                        className="btn btn-primary">{this.state.reservation.project.projectName}</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span className="caret"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <AvailableProjectsListBox reservation={this.state.reservation}
                                          onSelectProject={this.onSelectProject}/>
            </div>
            <div className="timesheet-column">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="timesheet-column">
                <input type="text" className="form-control timesheet-hour"
                       value={this.state.reservation.hours}
                       onChange={this.handleHoursChange}/>
            </div>
            <div className="timesheet-column">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
                    <span className="glyphicon  glyphicon-trash img-circle text-danger"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});


var AvailableProjectsListBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
       var onSelectProject = this.props.onSelectProject;
       var availableProjects = this.props.reservation.availableProjects.map(function (availableProject) {
            return (
                <AvailableProject availableProject={availableProject}     
onSelectProject={onSelectProject}/>
            );
        });
        return (
            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
               {availableProjects}
           </ul>
        );
   }
});

var AvailableProject = React.createClass({
    handleSelectProject: function () {
        this.props.onSelectProject(this.props.availableProject.project);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleSelectProject}>
                {this.props.availableProject.project.projectName}</a>
           </li>
        );
    }
});
```

I cannot modify input "hours" - it holds initial value. What's wrong in my approach ? How to handle this situation where I have large JSON object where many part of it will not be modified (so I pass them to nested components as props) and some of properties need to have modified state ?

EDIT: Now it works as I expected but I think it's BAD idea to updating JSON passed as "props" it must be better way to do it, but finally I keep my state 'project' and 'hours' in sync with JSON 'reservation' object. I would be grateful if someone experienced in React give me some hints how to do it correctly:

```
var ReservationBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            projectName: this.props.reservation.project.projectName,
            hours: this.props.reservation.hours
        }
    },
    onSelectProject: function (selectedProject) {
        this.setState({projectName: selectedProject.projectName});
        this.props.reservation.project = selectedProject;
    },
    handleHoursChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({hours: e.target.value})
        this.props.reservation.hours = e.target.value;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="btn-group timesheet-project-column">
                    <button type="button"
                            className="btn btn-primary">{this.state.projectName}</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span className="caret"></span>
                        <span className="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <AvailableProjectsListBox reservation={this.props.reservation}
                                              onSelectProject={this.onSelectProject}/>
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control timesheet-hour"
                           value={this.state.hours}
                           onChange={this.handleHoursChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className="timesheet-column">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
                        <span className="glyphicon  glyphicon-trash img-circle text-danger"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what *"THIS DOES NOT WORK"* means? Does it throw an error in the console or does it just fail silently?

Comment: Input field  "input type="text" className="form-control timesheet-hour"
                       value={this.state.reservation.hours}
                       onChange={this.handleHoursChange}/>" holds default value, that I assign in getInitialState. When I enter new one it is overwritten immediately by default.

Comment: Would you want to update the time in your database? Or you want to keep it local?

Comment: @jakeaaron I want to update view when I change hours and select project for given reservation from available projects list. But I also want to synchronize  changes with the JSON object I got from server because when user fill the whole form I want to sent this object back to the server to save in DB

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that this is a "bad" way of doing things.

In React, both Props and State should never be modified directly.  They are considered immutable.  You **can** change them directly (as you have done), but it interferes with the way React handles it's re-render loops, and you run the risk of either 1. Not updating when you should or 2. Having the props overwritten by the parent component.

However, React gives you the tools needed to modify State when you need to, via `this.setState({})`.  Just use that method, rather than directly changing the data.

You're already doing this inside of `handleHoursChange` on the first line.  The second line just needs to be removed.

If you need to pass things upstream to the parent component, the correct way to do it is by passing in a function as one of the props to the child.   A simple example might look like this;

```
var ReservationBoxParent = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(hours){
        //do something with hours here
    },
    render: function(){
        return <ReservationBox onChange={this.handleChange} reservation={this.props.reservation}/>;
    }
});

var ReservationBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {hours: this.props.reservation.hours}
    },
    handleHoursChange: function(hours){
        this.setState({hours: hours});
        this.props.onChange({hours: hours});
    },

    render: function(){
        return <input type="text"
                           value={this.state.hours}
                           onChange={this.handleHoursChange}/>
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I understand the concept of state and props in the component but setting the state of hours in ReservationBox component does update the view (it reflects current state of ReservationBox) only and I would like to update my global JSON object I got from server. I treat it as some "store" I got from server and user can modify it, user can do many modification one of them is setting hours, selecting project but there are many other inputs he can modify. After these modifications I would like to send this object to server to update in DB. ..

Comment: As I see in react debugger only 'state' property of react components is updated but now I want to update also my JSON obj (Now I do it by updating props but it is BAD). I've read about concept of global store and library like redux, but at first I want to do it in pure react to understand how it works.

Comment: what should I do in ReservationBoxParent to update 'this.props.reservation.hours = hours' in function 'handleChange' ?

Comment: Try creating `reservationWithUpdates` as part of the state in `ReservationBoxParent`.  Update this new slice of state in the `handleChange` function so that it reflects any user changes.  If you want to send the result to an API or whatnot, just reference that state object.  Could be something like `API.send(this.state.reservationWithUpdates)`